# how to know the path of the webcontainer using java?

Tags: java, file, jsp, servlets, path

I need to get the web container path using java, is there any method for that? I need to use it using JSP or Servlet to get a file path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *I need to use it using JSP or Servlet to get a file path.*

So the file is stored in the public webcontent of the WAR? Use [`ServletContext#getRealPath()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRealPath%28java.lang.String%29).

```
String relativeWebPath = "/file.jpg";
String absoluteDiskPath = getServletContext().getRealPath(relativeWebPath);
File file = new File(absoluteDiskPath);
InputStream input = new FileInputStream(file); // I guess this is what you want.
// ...
```

Note that this only works when the WAR is expanded by the container. Otherwise better use [`ServletContext#getResourceAsStream()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) if all you *really* want is to get an `InputStream` of it.

```
String relativeWebPath = "/file.jpg";
InputStream input = getServletContext().getResourceAsStream(relativeWebPath);
// ...
```

#### See also:

- [getResourceAsStream() vs FileInputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308188/getresourceasstream-vs-fileinputstream)

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for [`HttpServletRequest#getContextPath()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getContextPath%28%29):

> Returns the portion of the request URI that indicates the context of the request. The context path always comes first in a request URI. The path starts with a "/" character but does not end with a "/" character. For servlets in the default (root) context, this method returns "". The container does not decode this string.

...or [`getServletPath()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getServletPath%28%29):

> Returns the part of this request's URL that calls the servlet. This path starts with a "/" character and includes either the servlet name or a path to the servlet, but does not include any extra path information or a query string. Same as the value of the CGI variable SCRIPT_NAME.

Answer (score 0):

You're interested in [`getContextPath()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getContextPath%28%29) method of `HttpServletRequest`.